# UIScrollView forcing inside view to goes up after first touch

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView to pan some photos. After loading the view, when I touch the page (anywhere within) it makes my insideview (UIImageView) to goes up.
Here is the photo when it loads (the green is the inside UIView, the black the UIScrollView).

Fist load view:
[image: Image when it loads]

After the touch:
[image: After the first click]

Here is the code that generates it:

Adding the view to the scrollview:

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {

CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;

    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    // 3
    NSURL *eventImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page] imageURL]];
    UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [newPageView setImageWithURL:eventImageURL placeholderImage:nil usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    newPageView.frame=frame;
    newPageView.tag=page;
    newPageView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    newPageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    newPageView.clipsToBounds=YES;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
}
```

The scroll view setup:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

// 1

NSInteger pageCount = self.pageImages.count;

// 2
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

// 3
self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=2.0;
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds=YES;
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);
self.scrollView.tag=10;


[self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
On viewdidload I set:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

And everything works fine.